# Python - Download image from URL

Tags: python, image, download

I'm trying to download the following image: http://www.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR663.T.202202252249.png
Alternatively there's apparently an FTP link: ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/radar/

I've tried the following but none of it seems to work:

```py
def download_image(url):
    img_data = requests.get(url).content
    with open('image_name.png', 'wb') as handler:
        handler.write(img_data)

def download_image_2(url):
    with open('image_name.png', 'wb') as handle:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if not response.ok:
            print(response)

        for block in response.iter_content(1024):
            if not block:
                break

            handle.write(block)

def download_image_3(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print(response)
    file = open("image_name.png", "wb")
    file.write(response.content)
    file.close()

def download_image_4(url):
    # Downloading from an FTP stream
    with closing(req.urlopen(url)) as r:
        with open('image_name.png', 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)
```

Comment: If you click that link, you'll see "the page you requested is not found on this server."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOM doesn't allow webscraping. You can use their FTP server.

http://www.bom.gov.au/catalogue/anon-ftp.shtml

Note the radar images are only stored for 1.2 hours before being deleted.

This code gets all the filenames in the `/anon/gen/radar` directory, then makes a `list` with only the Brisbane/Mt Stapylton files, and finally only downloads and saves the files which haven't yet been downloaded and saved to disk.

You could run this every hour to get all the new images before they are deleted.

```py
import os
from ftplib import FTP

def get_brisbane_filenames(filename):
    if filename.startswith("IDR663.T."):
        brisbane_filenames.append(filename)

ftp = FTP(r"ftp.bom.gov.au")
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd("/anon/gen/radar")

brisbane_filenames = []
ftp.retrlines("NLST", get_brisbane_filenames)
   
for filename in brisbane_filenames:
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
            ftp.retrbinary(f"RETR {filename}", fp.write)
            print(f"Downloaded and saved {filename}")

ftp.quit()
```